# Finding a value using an input box

Tags: excel, vba

So I get these canned reports that have a lot of transactions on them and I've written a macro that adds a column (always in Column L) that calculates how old each transaction is and then sorts them newest to oldest.

My goal is to add an input box where the end-user can specify a number of days overdue (say 50), and then the code will find the first instance of that value and copy everything in that row to the end and move it to a new sheet.

Here is my current sub just finding the data (ignore the columnheadings part as that's just copying over the headings)

```
Sub FindAndCopyData()

Dim ColumnHeadings As Range

Dim FirstCell As Range

Set ColumnHeadings = Range("A1:L1")

ColumnHeadings.Copy Sheets("Overdue Receipts").Range("A1")

Set FirstCell = Range("L:L").Find(What:=InputBox("How many days overdue"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
End Sub
```

This is just returning the value of whatever I put into the input box instead of the address where that value first shows up. Thankful for any help!

Comment: `Range.Find` returns a `Range`, not an address string, and not a value either. If you want the address of the range returned, that would be `FirstCell.Address` - beware though, if `Range.Find` doesn't find anything, that member call will raise error 91. Also, consider making the `Range.Find` call conditional to the `InputBox` not being cancelled.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks for the help! so I changed where it says "Set FirstCell = Range... " to "Set FirstCell.Address = Range..." and I get the error "Assignment to constant not permitted"

Comment: You can't assign to `Range.Address`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range.Find` returns a `Range` reference, not a value, and not an address. You can get the address of any `Range` object through its `Address` property.

Split up your code, you have way too many things going on in a single instruction:

```
Dim userInput As Variant
userInput = InputBox(...)
If StrPtr(userInput) = 0 Then
    'inputbox was cancelled
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim findResult As Range
Set findResult = ActiveSheet.Range("L:L").Find(CStr(userInput), ...)

If findResult Is Nothing Then
    'did not find anything
    Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox findResult.Address
```

Comment: This is great! a couple additional q's about it. So for the last line that has the msgbox: so my goal here is to find the address from the find function and load that into a variable and then from there copy all cells below and to the left of it. could I declare a variable at the top and say "findResult.address = (name of variable) and then variable.range plus end xl down/end xl left and then copy that?

Comment: You need to take it the other way around, `someRange.Address = (whatever)` is not legal, because `Range.Address` is read-only. You want `someVariable = someRange.Address`. The target of an assignment is always on the left-hand side of the `=` assignment operator.

Comment: Also some cases might not have a cell with 50 days overdue, but it would have something with 49 days and another with 52 days for example. I want the code to find the first cell equal to or greater than whatever value is put into the input box. Do you know how I could incorporate that into the Find process?

Comment: FWIW I don't think the address is relevant for that task. You have a full-fledged `Range` object, its address is just metadata. `findResult.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)` gets you a `Range` that's exactly 1 column to the left of `findResult`

Comment: `Range.Find` isn't going to handle fuzzy matches AFAIK. You're going to have to iterate the cells and determine if they're within the acceptable range of values.